# Is adding a Back button and/or a Next Question button a good UI/UX decision?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, navigation

In terms of UI/UX it is a good decision, also for accessibility reasons. But is it worth the screen space it takes?

To clarify, I'm talking about a **Back** button that would take you the previous questions page. The same for **Next Question** button, only this would take you the next question in the order of the previous questions page. Everybody knows what these buttons are.

On the other hand, not many websites have those. Some do. Let's take a website with listings page and a single entry page. Hmm... Amazon and eBay have a "back to results" button. Google Images has a "Next result" arrow.

Indeed it's a matter of opinion. What do you think?

Comment: *Please* be sure to read the [info for the feature request tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info) and edit this request with more information.

Comment: Re *"take you the previous questions page"*: What is the current page then? Can you [provide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/380112/edit) an example? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)

Comment: Most people come for the question/answers page and it's the focus of this discussion. *Its* previous page is the questions (aka list) page. If you came from the list page, it will take you back to the list page (same filter). If you came from google, it would take you the list page, this time on most popular filter, thus increasing user engagement time :-P. I provided 3 examples.

Comment: @ITgoldman "previous," in that context, is equivalent to the "back" button in your browser.